# How to handle Tel with WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am able to show the dialer, but the phone number doesn't show up. Where am I going wrong?

This is my code.

```
if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

                    startActivity(intent); 
                }
```

So again my problem is with the number, the number doesn't show up on the dialer. So my real question to you, How do you grab that number?

Answer (score 0):

It just had to be in this format **Intent (String action, Uri uri)**

```
if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(url));

startActivity(intent); 
                        }
```